# Building spark-jobserver Using SBT and Scala

Tags: rest, apache-spark, spark-jobserver

Can anyone suggest me a better documentation about spark-jobserver. I have gone through the url [spark-jobserver](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver) but unable to follow the same. It will be great if some one explain step by step instruction on how to use spark-jobserver.

Tools used in building the project.

- sbt launcher version 0.13.5
- Scala code runner version 2.11.6

With the above mentioned tools I am getting errors while building the spark-jobserver.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation provided in the jobserver repo is indeed confusing.

Here's the steps I followed to manually build and run Spark Job Server on a local machine.

```
1. git clone https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver
2. sudo mkdir -p /var/log/job-server
3. sudo chown user1:user1 /var/log/job-server
4. cd spark-jobserver
5. sbt job-server/assembly
6. cd config
7. cp local.sh.template abc.sh  # Note that the same name 'abc' is used in steps 8 and 10 as well
8. cp ec2.conf.template abc.conf
9. cd .. # The jobserver root dir
10. ./bin/server_package.sh abc # This script copies the files and packages necessary to run job server into a single dir [ default - /tmp/job-server]
11. cd /tmp/job-server [This is where the files and packages necessary to run job server are published by default]
12. ./server_start.sh
13. Run ./server_stop.sh to stop the server
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps that I used to install:

1. Clone the jobserver repo.
2. Get sbt using `wget https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/native-packages/sbt/0.13.8/sbt-0.13.8.tgz`
3. Move "sbt-launch.jar" in sbt/bin to /bin
4. Create a script /bin/sbt, contents found [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Manual-Installation.html), making sure to change the pointer to java if necessary
5. Make the above script executable
6. Now cd into the spark jobserver directory, and run `sbt publish-local`
7. Assuming the above was successful, run `sbt` in the same directory
8. Finally, use the command `re-start`, and if it succeeds the server is now running!

Comment: step 3 doesn't look like a good idea and the link in step 4 is dead.